# Send users to page after form submit

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP contact form, and once a user has successfully filled out the form they see the "Message sent" message under the form.

**PHP code**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($name_error) && !isset($subject_error) && !isset($email_error) && !isset($message_error)){
  $to = 'youremail@addres.com'; // edit here
  $body = " Name: $name\n E-mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
  if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
    echo '<p style="color: green">Message sent</p>';
  }else{
    echo '<p>Error occurred, please try again later</p>';
  }
}
?>
```

However, refreshing the form after the form has been submitted the page would send the form details again and again. How can I redirect a user to say: `http://www.example.com/thanks` after they have submitted the form successfully?

EDIT: I am not sure how to redirect within the form itself, I know how to redirect with PHP, just not in this script.

Comment: `header("Location: https://www.google.com");` This must be called before any other output is sent.

Comment: Thank you Matt, So remove the echo and replace with header("Location: https://www.google.com"); ? Sorry not a PHP pro.